# How to annotate the type of a list of functions with different output type in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, python-typing, typing

The following `try_parse` method takes as input a value of type `T` and a series of functions with input type `T`. The functions do not necessarily have to have the same output type, e.g., it could be `int`, `float`, `MyCustomClass` etc. How would I appropriately annotate the function type in this code?

```
T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")

def try_parse(value: T, *parse_functions: Callable[[T], U]) -> U:
    for parse_function in parse_functions:
        try:
            return parse_function(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError(f"Cannot parse {value} with any of {parse_functions}")
```

Answer (score 4):

One way to annotate your `try_parse` method, assuming you want to keep the code flexible but still benefit from type checking to some extent, is to type parse_functions as a sequence of callables where each callable takes an input of type `T` and returns a value of type `Any`. This approach sacrifices some type specificity for flexibility:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Callable, Any

T = TypeVar("T")

def try_parse(value: T, *parse_functions: Callable[[T], Any]) -> Any:
    for parse_function in parse_functions:
        try:
            return parse_function(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError(f"Cannot parse {value} with any of {parse_functions}")
```

`Any` is used for the return type of `parse_functions` and the return type of `try_parse` itself, indicating that the function can return any type, which aligns with your requirement that `parse_functions` could have varying output types. While this approach reduces the benefits of static type checking by introducing `Any`, it reflects the dynamic nature of your `try_parse` function more accurately.

If you're working in a context where you can guarantee that all functions in parse_functions will return the same type, or if you're okay with enforcing that constraint, you could stick with the original annotation using U as the return type. However, based on your description, it seems like using Any is closer to your intention for this function.

Comment: That is to say, it is currently impossible to provide a signature with the semantics "the function's output type is the union of the output types of all functions in `parse_functions`"?

Comment: Well if it is, I don’t know how to do it!

Comment: Yep, nothing more precise is possible until you get TypeVarTuple transformations (because `TypeVarTuple` is very close to what you want here, but you need to unpack it as sequence of callables, not as a single callable with one tuple). Here's the relevant issue (PEP is still not there AFAIC): https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1216